# Tun/tap installation

Tags: vpn, openvpn

i have got a virtual private server with Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 2.6.32-5-openvz-amd64 x86_64).
I want to install openvpn but this requires a working tun device.
i get the following error:

```
Note: Cannot open TUN/TAP dev /dev/net/tun: Operation not permitted (errno=1)
```

# modprobe tun

```
WARNING: Deprecated config file /etc/modprobe.conf, all config files belong into /etc/modprobe.d/.
FATAL: Module tun not found.
```

What do i have to do to get this tun running?

Comment: have you make sure the configuration is correct?

Comment: i dont know how to check this.

Comment: OpenVZ VPS doesn't offer tun/tap by default. If you are renting this server, ask your provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will have to ask your VPS provider to enable TUN/TAP.
If they won't enable TUN/TAP you can't use openvpn.